# phpmyadmin: "Cannot connect: invalid settings.", but only for 'users' tab

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, credentials

So I've been having problems connecting to my phpmyAdmin server, but I've got it fixed by editing the config.inc.php file inside the PMA folder and changing my username to root and a password as root, so it now looks like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
```

This is all good, my website connects in a similar manner to the database using the same credentials. The problem is, I can't access the 'Users' tab inside the PHPMyAdmin interface- I get this error lumped in a lovely red dialog:

```
MySQL said:
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the 
connection. You should check the host, username and password in your 
configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given 
by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I know this is ridiculous, since I have full access to all databases and settings and my credentials are correct. Anyone know why this is?

Note I'm running XAMPP 3.1.0, Apache 2.4.7, & MySQL 5.5.27 in a windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a new user for the database? You should avoid using the root user and create a new user for each database, and use that one instead.